# What does Exposure Bias 12/6 EV mean?

Tags: exposure

is this the same as EV +2? which is two steps from 'normal exposure'.

It was taken from the information on a photo I saw taken with a Nikon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, yes, 2 EV. In some cases a space is missing, that is it is 1 2/6 EV, or 1 1/3 EV.

Comment: Why would it be displayed in these odd fractions?

Comment: Probably because the cameras that do it this way have exposure bias steps that are set at 1/6 stop. By stating it as 12/6, it is easy to see the photographer moved the *EC* dial 12 clicks. If the camera displayed it as 6/3, then we would know the user had 1/3 stop steps selected when the photo was taken.

Comment: @mattdm, Exposure Bias tag 0x9204 in EXIF standard is specified as signed rational, that is represented by 2 numbers forming a fraction. Nikon are using '6' as denominator. 1/12 is internal calibration by the way.